# get records created within 24 hour in sails js

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I want to fetch the `Posts` which are created within 24 hours in sails js. And I am using `mongodb` database. How do I get all those Posts which are created in past 24 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a date range that consists of 24 hours in the following manner.

Using the momentjs library, you can create a date with the extension methods **[`subtract()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/)** and cast it to a JS Date with the **[`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/)** method:

```
var start = moment().subtract(24, 'hours').toDate();
```

or with plain vanilla Date objects, create the date range as:

```
var now = new Date(),
    start = new Date(now.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Use the **[`where()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/where)** method to use the query the `Posts` model using the above date range query, given the field which holds the timestamp is called `date`:

```
Posts.find()
    .where({ "date" : { ">": start } })
    .exec(function (err, posts) {
        if (err) throw err;
        return res.json(posts);
    });
```

Comment: ```"<" : end``` is not required, because there will be no records created in future. It would make sence if you want records from -48 to -24 hours. But not from -24 to 0.

Comment: @Bonanza You are right, silly of me I was assuming there would be posts set to auto-publish for a given future date :P But then again the OP never mentioned that.

Comment: i haven't thought about auto-publish. :)